# Node.js require helper file with const is throwing function not defined error but working with var and let

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've a utility file which contains a set of helper functions.

**utility.js**

```
module.exports = {

    encrypt: function (text) {
        let cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password)
        let crypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex')
        crypted += cipher.final('hex');
        return crypted;
    },
    decrypt: function (text) {
        let decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, password)
        let dec = decipher.update(text, 'hex', 'utf8')
        dec += decipher.final('utf8');
        return dec;
    }
};
```

When I require utility in my routes or models files like this

```
const utility = require('../functions/utility');
utility.encrypt("asdsadsa");
```

**It throws this error: TypeError: utility.encrypt is not a function**

**but when I require utility module with let or var keyword like this it works fine**

```
let utility = require('../functions/utility');
utility.encrypt("asdsadsa");
```

I'm not understanding why it's happening. I know the difference between const, let and var and as per my limited knowledge this shouldn't happen. Please help me in this regard why it's happening.

Bundle of thanks.

Comment: There's no difference between your two require examples.

Comment: Exactly, but on the production environment this is what happening and I'm totally confused with this kind of behavior.

Comment: There has to be something else that you miss here, as both will work correctly considering this very simple snippet only.